# Изменение порядка элементов в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой массив:

```
[0] = > array(4) {
    ["season"] = > string(3)"6 "
    ["episodeNum"] = > string(3)"0 "
    ["airDate"] = > string(2)" "
    ["title"] = > string(36)"Epilogue: The New Man in Charge
"
}

[1] = > array(4) {
    ["season"] = > string(3)"6 "
    ["episodeNum"] = > string(4)"18 "
    ["airDate"] = > string(12)"23.05.2010 "
    ["title"] = > string(16)"The End (2)
"
}

[2] = > array(4) {
    ["season"] = > string(3)"6 " 
    ["episodeNum"] = > string(4)"17 " 
    ["airDate"] = > string(12)"23.05.2010 " 
    ["title"] = > string(16)"The End (1)
"
}

[25] = > array(4) {
    ["season"] = > string(3)"5 " 
    ["episodeNum"] = > string(4)"14 " 
    ["airDate"] = > string(12)"29.04.2009 " 
    ["title"] = > string(17)"The Variable
"
}

[26] = > array(4) {
    ["season"] = > string(3)"5 " 
    ["episodeNum"] = > string(3)"0 " 
    ["airDate"] = > string(12)"22.04.2009 " 
    ["title"] = > string(31)"The Story of the Oceanic 6
"
}

[27] = > array(4) {
    ["season"] = > string(3)"5 " 
    ["episodeNum"] = > string(4)"13 " 
    ["airDate"] = > string(12)"15.04.2009 " 
    ["title"] = > string(22)"Some Like It Hoth
"
}
```

Нужно разбить массив по `season`. В массиве описание сериала, номера сезона и серии, а также название и дата. Нужно сделать так, чтобы в массиве первым шел номер сезона, а потом уже остальное содержимое в текущем порядке.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = [];
// $array - ваш массив
foreach($array as $series){
    $newArray[$series['season']][] = $series;
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Получится массив вида

```
сериал => 
    сезон 1 =>
        серия 1
        серия 2
    сезон 2 =>
        серия 1
        серия 2
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Удачного дня... Все работает

Comment: Тут вопрос встречный а как все таки сделать чтоб не номер сезона был а просто слово сезон ?

Comment: Если это не то, что вы хотите, напишите в вопросе образец массива на выходе. Сделать-то можно, что угодно, но зачем гадать, что вам надо